# iptables rule order

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I have noticed the following iptables rule order executed by a program:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p all -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p all -s ip_address -j REJECT
```

I thought that based on the ordering principle of iptables, this would lead to the second line being ignored (ie. the ip_address will not be rejected because all connections are already accepted by the first line). Does it mean that this program is misconfigured?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yup, you're right! test it to verify.

Comment: Ya i tested it but i wasn't sure if I missed something. It confuses me when a reputable program does something unexpected. thanks for your confirmation!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the rules will be executed in that order. Assuming there are no other interrelated rules not displayed in your question, this won't deny the host with `-s ip_address` ip address. If you want that ip address to be rejected, replace `-A` (Append) with `-I` (Insert).

```
/sbin/iptables -I -p all -s ip_address -j REJECT
```